# Paraboloid and Sphere

Tags: calculus, integration, geometry, multivariable-calculus, spherical-coordinates

> Find the volume of the solid region inside the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=6$ and above the paraboloid $z=x^2+y^2.$

I set both equations equal to each other and obtained $z=2$ and $z=-3$. Since clearly $z>0,$ that means I only consider $z=2.$ Subbing this into both equations gives $x^2+y^2=2$.

I sketch this circle and obtain $0 \leq \theta \leq 2 \pi$ and $0 \leq r \leq \sqrt2.$ Also, clearly $r^2 \leq z \leq \sqrt{6-r^2}.$

Now I want to convert into spherical coordinates. I don't know how to find the limits for $\phi$. I think the lower limit is $0$ but I am not sure about the upper limit. I think the upper limit for $p$ is $6$. Not sure how to find the rest.

Comment: Cylindrical coordinates will do it, I find them more appropriate. You have everything what needed for them.

Comment: @user376343 I would like to convert into spherical coordinates as well though. I think I may also have $ 0 \leq \phi \leq \frac{\pi}{2} $ but I am not sure.

Comment: Extremal values for $\phi$ are not constant.

Comment: @user376343 Okay. How would I find them out then? And what about for $p$? The only thing I can think of is converting the two equations given to me into spherical coordinates and then rearranging to make $p$ the subject. Not sure about $\phi$ right now but a sketch may help?

Comment: What do you call $p$?

Comment: @user376343 The distance from the origin to a point ($x$, $y$, $z$). Also known as $\rho$ I guess.

Comment: I'll assume that you used $\rho, \theta$ and $\phi$ as spherical coordinates such that $z=\rho \cos \phi$. Next, with $z=2$ and $\rho=\sqrt6$ you will have an awkward upper bound for $\phi$.

Comment: @AntonVrdoljak Just a question about this - for rectangular coordinates, the order of $dz$ $dx$ and $dy$ matter right. It also matters for cylindrical coordinates. Does the same apply to spherical coordinates? Does the order matter?

Comment: To @Dam: Yes, the order matter while we have to calculate multiple-integrals in some other coordinates too...